# Google Maps how to dynamically update url with map lat , long and zoom?

Tags: google-maps

how can it be done like in here :

http://www.360cities.net/map#lat=-25.87899&lng=-42.45117&zoom=4

Every time we move and zoom in the map, the url dynamically updates .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not difficult, observe the `bounds_changed`-event of the map and when it fires retrieve the map-properties and assign them to the hash-property of the location-object:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed',function(){
      location.hash='lat='+this.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6)+
                    '&lng='+this.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6)+
                    '&zoom='+this.getZoom();

    });
```

Comment: Fantastic ! That´s it! Eternal gratitude :)